# Submitting form gives MethodNotAllowedHttpException error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a moderation queue as part of an application I'm building. Users can submit questionnaire's but they need to be moderated by an admin.

I've built the functionality for the queue and can load the answers they submit on to a page, but I'm having trouble implementing an approve/reject button.

I'm wanting the page to display their answers, which it does, and then down the bottom have a button to approve and then a button to reject (with a textbox for the reason).

When either button is clicked, I'm trying to update the table appropriately - however I'm just getting an error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:`.

I don't understand why as I built the user administration function in a similar way without any trouble.

Can anyone help, or suggest a better way to do what I'm doing:

**Routes**

```
Route::resource('/questionnaire', 'QuestionnaireController');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;
use Input;
use Redirect;
use App\Questionnaire;
use App\User;
use DB;

class QuestionnaireController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('questionnaire.index');
    }

    public function moderate()
    {
        $questionnaires = DB::table('users')
                        ->join('questionnaire', 'users.id', '=', 'questionnaire.memberid')
                        ->select('users.username', 'questionnaire.*')
                        ->get();
        return view('questionnaire.moderate', ['questionnaires' => $questionnaires]);
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        $questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($id);

        return view('questionnaire.view', ['questionnaire' => $questionnaire]);
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $questionnaire = new Questionnaire;

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'q1' => 'required|between:128,512',
            'q2' => 'required|between:128,512',
            'q3' => 'required|between:128,512',
            'q4' => 'required|between:128,512',
            'q5' => 'required|between:128,512',
        ], [
            'q1.required' => 'The first answer is empty!',
            'q2.required' => 'The second answer is empty!',
            'q3.required' => 'The third answer is empty!',
            'q4.required' => 'The fourth answer is empty!',
            'q5.required' => 'The fifth answer is empty!',
            'q1.between' => 'The first answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'q2.between' => 'The second answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'q3.between' => 'The third answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'q4.between' => 'The fourth answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'q5.between' => 'The fifth answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/questionnaire')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        $questionnaire->memberid = $request->memberid;
        $questionnaire->q1 = $request->q1;
        $questionnaire->q2 = $request->q2;
        $questionnaire->q3 = $request->q3;
        $questionnaire->q4 = $request->q4;
        $questionnaire->q5 = $request->q5;

        $questionnaire->save();

        $id = $request->memberid;
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->confirmed = 1;

        $user->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($id);
        return view('questionnaire.show', ['questionnaire' => $questionnaire]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($id);
        return view('questionnaire.edit', ['questionnaire' => $questionnaire]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $questionnaire = Questionnaire::find($id);
        $button = Input::get('buttonid');

        if ($button == "approve")
        {
            $questionnaire->status = 3;
            $questionnaire->save();
            return redirect('questionnaire/moderate');
        }

        if ($button == "reject")
        {
            $questionnaire->status = 2;
            $questionnaire->rejectreason = Input::get('rejectreason');
            $questionnaire->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**View** Which can be found at the URI /questionnaire/{membersid}/edit

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    <div class='col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4'>

        @if (Auth::guest())
            You need to be logged in to use this page.
        @else


            <h1><i class='fa fa-user'></i> Review Questionnaire</h1>

           <h3>Question 1:</h3>
            {{$questionnaire->q1}}

            <h3>Question 2:</h3>
            {{$questionnaire->q2}}

            <h3>Question 3:</h3>
            {{$questionnaire->q3}}

            <h3>Question 4:</h3>
            {{$questionnaire->q4}}

            <h3>Question 5:</h3>
            {{$questionnaire->q5}}
            <br />
            <br />
            {!! Form::model($questionnaire, ['role' => 'form', 'url' => '/questionnaire/' . $questionnaire->memberid . '/edit', 'method' => 'PUT'])!!}
            {!! Form::hidden('memberid', $questionnaire->memberid) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Approve', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'buttonid', 'value' => 'approve']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Reject', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'buttonid', 'id' => 'buttonid', 'value' => 'reject']) !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('rejectreason', null, ['placeholder' => "Reason why you're rejecting... please be specific as the member will read this", 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        @endif

    </div>

@endsection
```

When I click either button though, I get the error below:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

in RouteCollection.php line 201
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 188
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 140
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I viewed other questions, but they seem specific to their set up. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your form opener to

```
{!! Form::model($questionnaire, ['role' => 'form', 'url' => '/questionnaire/' . $questionnaire->memberid, 'method' => 'PUT'])!!}
```

You are sending the request to /edit which is incorrect. Take a look at the table of routes for resource controllers in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) which shows the allowed methods.

Edit: You'll find you will avoid these type of errors if you use the route names for resources instead of manually building the URL.

Comment: When I submit form with your changes it still doesn't update the database though?

Comment: I suspect neither of the conditions in your update method are being met.

What does `dd(Input::get('buttonid'));` output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating a questionnaire, it means it already exists. You don't have to save it but update. And, you have to pass the data, like so:

```
$questionnaire->update(Request::all());
```

P.S: that's on top of what Alex said, that was perfect too.